# How to edit java files in remote machine using eclipse

Tags: eclipse

my project source code is in unix, we are using CM synergy source control for code checkin/chech out files. we update the files using vi editor. Pls help in how to set up eclipse in windows system and then connect to the code server and edit the files.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [Remote System Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm) framework, that allows opening files from a remote server, and also gives shell access to the remote server. For anything more specific, I'm not sure whether a free solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced some problems accessing remote file systems with the Remote System Explorer Plugin, the FTP session was closed unexpectedly. I recommend for linking in your local projects remote sites [Aptana Eclipse Plugin](http://www.aptana.com/).